# express-jwt not accessing .env variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, express-jwt

I have `dotenv`, `jsonwebtoken`, and `express-jwt` packages.

When I create a token with `jsonwebtoken` the env variable is found and works as expected:

```
...
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: "7d",
        });
    ...
```

However, when I use the express-jwt package with this code:

```
router.get(
    "/current-user",
    expressjwt({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        algorithms: ["HS256"],
    }),
    currentUser
);
```

I get the following error:

```
RangeError: express-jwt: `secret` is a required option
```

I can workaround the error by hard coding the secret string in like so:

```
...
secret: "mySuperSecret",
...
```

A hard coded string is what is shown in the official documentation; obviously, this isn't a realistic solution.

I'm using the .env variables successfully in several places (port, database, signing the token).

Why is the .env variable not being picked up by this one package, or in this one option?

Comment: Have you checked, if the environment variables are accessable in the file, where you use express-jwt?
Have you tried defining a variable for the secret within the file and then use that for express-jwt?

Comment: Thank you @Geshode  In my root server.js file I call dotenv.config(). I did this again in the middleware file. This fixed the issue. However, I'm still not entirely clear why I had to do it in this one middleware file when I did not have to do the same in my controller file (where the token is signed with the env variable). Any ideas? Also, what is the performance impact of doing this in multiple places (assuming I run into this issue over and over)?

Comment: Kept playing around. Deleted the dotenv package import from the root server.js file and only buried it on the one middleware file. Now, even though the first command in the server.js file is to console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET) that command works. I understand the async nature of node.js but am now super confused at how it is queuing and executing commands. I would expect that to return quickly as "undefined" since it would take relatively longer for the rest of the functions to execute.